# JVM/App just pauses indefinitely

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I am having a weird problem where my application just pauses. I have looked at the CPU consumption, eden & tenured heap is all way under the max limit.

```
sudo /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_60/bin/jstat -gc 19656 10000
 S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       PC     PU    YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT
273024.0 273024.0  0.0   47919.3 2184576.0 457104.3 5461376.0  2920470.4  39932.0 23950.2   1094  926.334  348   338.201 1264.535
273024.0 273024.0  0.0   47919.3 2184576.0 457172.3 5461376.0  2920470.4  39932.0 23950.2   1094  926.334  348   338.201 1264.535
```

But I always observe a series of ParNew collections (the below log messages) in gc outputs just before when the app gets stuck:

```
24676.082: [GC24676.082: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 139788288 bytes, new threshold 1 (max 6)
- age   1:  178588280 bytes,  178588280 total
: 2184576K->273024K(2457600K), 0.2795420 secs] 4892724K->2981179K(7918976K), 0.2797780 secs] [Times: user=1.11 sys=0.00, real=0.28 secs]
 CMS: abort preclean due to time 24679.377: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 5.784/6.654 secs] [Times: user=12.64 sys=3.47, real=6.65 secs]
24679.378: [GC[YG occupancy: 487069 K (2457600 K)]24679.378: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.2062950 secs]24679.584: [weak refs processing, 0.0008070 secs]24679.585: [scrub string table, 0.0002830 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 2708155K(5461376K)] 3195224K(7918976K), 0.2075960 secs] [Times: user=0.82 sys=0.00, real=0.21 secs]
24679.585: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
24680.597: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 1.006/1.012 secs] [Times: user=1.81 sys=0.00, real=1.01 secs]
24680.597: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
24680.617: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.020/0.020 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]
24734.856: [GC24734.856: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 139788288 bytes, new threshold 6 (max 6)
- age   1:    7286744 bytes,    7286744 total
: 2457600K->198236K(2457600K), 0.4687370 secs] 5165750K->3118706K(7918976K), 0.4689730 secs] [Times: user=1.78 sys=0.00, real=0.47 secs]
24793.336: [GC24793.336: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 139788288 bytes, new threshold 6 (max 6)
- age   1:    7275368 bytes,    7275368 total
- age   2:    6778992 bytes,   14054360 total
: 2382812K->50896K(2457600K), 0.1408800 secs] 5303282K->2971366K(7918976K), 0.1411080 secs] [Times: user=0.56 sys=0.00, real=0.14 secs]
24859.251: [GC24859.251: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 139788288 bytes, new threshold 6 (max 6)
- age   1:    6916184 bytes,    6916184 total
- age   2:    6789648 bytes,   13705832 total
- age   3:    6773040 bytes,   20478872 total
: 2235472K->32310K(2457600K), 0.1847690 secs] 5155942K->2952781K(7918976K), 0.1850020 secs] [Times: user=0.71 sys=0.00, real=0.18 secs]
24932.033: [GC24932.033: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 139788288 bytes, new threshold 6 (max 6)
- age   1:    6150464 bytes,    6150464 total
- age   2:    6514336 bytes,   12664800 total
- age   3:    6783960 bytes,   19448760 total
- age   4:    6769808 bytes,   26218568 total
: 2216886K->38073K(2457600K), 0.2244340 secs] 5137357K->2958543K(7918976K), 0.2246640 secs] [Times: user=0.89 sys=0.00, real=0.22 secs]
24994.753: [GC24994.754: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 139788288 bytes, new threshold 6 (max 6)
- age   1:    5031544 bytes,    5031544 total
- age   2:    5847368 bytes,   10878912 total
- age   3:    6509216 bytes,   17388128 total
- age   4:    6781200 bytes,   24169328 total
- age   5:    6768376 bytes,   30937704 total
: 2222649K->47919K(2457600K), 0.2667860 secs] 5143119K->2968389K(7918976K), 0.2669990 secs] [Times: user=1.06 sys=0.00, real=0.27 secs]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the PermGen? I notice that you are using CMS. I don't think CMS scans perm space by default.

Comment: Yes its almost half of the limit